# How to link from ordered list to another div?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Ok so i want to know how to create two divs. In one you have a order list of names. And in the other div on the same page you have properties about that name.

like so :

```
<div id="list_of_names">
<ul>
        <li>names</li>
           <ul>
               <li><a href=" div link ? ">name1</a></li>
               <li>name2</li>
               <li>name3</li>
               <li>name4</li>
           </ul>

</ul>
</div>
```

and in the other some pictures or other data about that name appears.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you just need to add ids to those div you want to link. Like:

```
<div id="info_1"></div>
<div id="info_2"></div>
```

And then add their link on your `a` like this

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#info_1">name1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#info_2">name2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And you are done.

### Update

If you want to make show/hide instead of linking then here below is the example. Use jQuery on your project and organize your project something like this. I have added extra css style. Change them to give your own styling.

```js
$('#index_list').on('click', 'a', function(e) {

  //Prevent default link to work
  e.preventDefault();

  //Taking the id link from href attr
  var selectedDom = $(this).attr('href');

  //Doing show/hide
  $('#content_wrap > div').fadeOut();
  $(selectedDom).fadeIn();

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

.index_list {
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #22A7F0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.index_list>li>a {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 2;
}

.content_wrap {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #19B5FE;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content_wrap>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#info_1 {
  background-color: #F9690E;
}

#info_2 {
  background-color: #049372;
}

#info_3 {
  background-color: #BF55EC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="index_list" id="index_list">
  <li><a href="#info_1">name1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#info_2">name2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#info_3">name3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content_wrap" id="content_wrap">
  <div id="info_1">
    Here is 1st content
  </div>
  <div id="info_2">
    Here is 2nd content
  </div>
  <div id="info_3">
    Here is 3rd content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And if you want content to change you than have to "stack" divs on top of each other? So that you click one and only info about that one appears ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. By `stack` do you mean `overlay`? If so and also you want your content to show/hide on button click then update your question, please.

Comment: Yes like that. I want them to overlay. So that when i click on one of the items from the list new content appears overpaying previous one.

Comment: I have update the answer with your query. On future, be sure to add enough information on question to get help quickly.